# LogParser Access Denied error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, logging, logparser

I using Logparser to parse IIS Log and show information on a web page. Everything is working fine in my development environment but once I publish the application to server I get the following error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {8CFEBA94-3FC2-45CA-B9A5-9EDACF704F66} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {8CFEBA94-3FC2-45CA-B9A5-9EDACF704F66} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

What does this error means and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dedicated application pool for site and switch its identity to "Network Services". Solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

You may need to give the user it's running under on the server DCOM permission to run it.
DCOM config is located in Component Services and you can see the GUIDs for each entry so you should be able to identify the relevant entry.

Then edit the security permissions for it and give the relevant user Launch and Activation permissions and Access permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because of lack of permissions.
You need to give the read/write permission to IIS Users/Guest in Virtual Directory.

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7+ may not be configured to run 32 bit applications. From your Application Pool, navigate to Advanced Settings, and Enable 32 bit applications.

I encountered the same issue you describe, and the steps I took to resolve it included:

- Enabling 32 bit applications under the app pool
- From the log folders (inetpub/logs/LogFiles/{site}, granting access to the app pool identity
- Copying the LogParser.dll and Interop.MSUtil.dll to the site's bin folder

Answer (score 0):

The steps I used to resolve the problem are as follows:

1. Go to IIS Manager
2. Navigate to the site in question
3. enable the ASP.NET authentication for your default website

This should clear up the permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to try three things:

1- See if the LogParser.dll was registred with regsvr32.exe;
2- Change permission on Application Pool to Network Service;
3- Accept 32-bit applications on Application Pool;